# Rails Validations, number + letters + spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking for a Rails validation that will only allow letters, numbers, and spaces.
This will do letters and numbers, but no spaces.
I need spaces.

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /^\w+$/i,
:message => "can only contain letters and numbers."
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /^[a-zA-Z\d ]*$/i,
:message => "can only contain letters and numbers."
```

Here is only Number, Letters ans spaces.

Is that exactly what you need ?

PS : This tools is very useful if you are doing a lot of reg-exp : http://rubular.com/

Comment: Yea, that works! that link looks great, makes me want to learn the most confusing syntax ever!

Comment: This will also match empty strings (you can change the * to a + to match strings of at least one char).

Comment: This matches underscores, and `\w` already matches numbers so you don't need `\d`.

Comment: Thanks guys deed some see any possible breach now ?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\z/i, message: "can only contain letters and numbers." }
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want letters, numbers, and spaces, but not underscores, the accepted answer won't work for you. The following also won't allow empty strings, but it wouldn't matter either way if the rails model has `validates_presence_of :name`

```
/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize underscore was in there